# Discord Bot replies undefined in Embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

[image]

My bot only replies undefined with two variables, although I actually defined them.
I dont know why it not works pls help

The command is: you press the button enter a reason and a game in the text input field and then you select a platform from the drop down menu. But instead of sending the embed it says undefined.

My Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Command = require('../../structures/CommandClass');
const { stripIndents } = require('common-tags');
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, TextInputStyle, StringSelectMenuBuilder, Events, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder } = require('discord.js');


    
module.exports = class spielersuche extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
                .setName('sendspielersuche')
                .setDescription('Sende das Spielersuche Embed')
                .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
                .setDMPermission(false),          
        });
    }
        
      
  async run(client, interaction) {
    let member = await interaction.member.fetch();
    const anfragechannelID = '889302458906591344';
    const anfragechannel =  member.guild.channels.cache.get(anfragechannelID);
    const createanfragechannelID = '1061113274130772058';
    const createanfragechannel =  member.guild.channels.cache.get(createanfragechannelID);
   
  
    

      const pfmenü = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('pfmenü')
                    .setPlaceholder('Plattform auswählen')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'PS4',                           
                            value: 'ps4',
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'PS5',                           
                            value: 'ps5',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'PS4/PS5',                           
                            value: 'ps4ps5',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'PC',                        
                            value: 'pc',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Switch',                            
                            value: 'switch',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Alle',      
                            value: 'alle',
                        },
                    ),
            );


      
      const modals = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('minput')
            .setTitle('Spielersuche ');


      const spielinput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('spielinput') 
            .setLabel("Für welches Spiel?")
      .setPlaceholder('GTA5, Fortnite, Call of Duty, Minecraft ...')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setMinLength(2)
      .setMaxLength(20)
      .setRequired(true);

      const grundinput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('grundinput')         
            .setLabel("Der Grund der Anfrage?")   
      .setPlaceholder('Beispiel: Suche Spieler für Cayo Perico Heist.') 
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setMinLength(10)
      .setMaxLength(60)
      .setRequired(true);
      
      const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(spielinput);
      const secondActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(grundinput);
      modals.addComponents(firstActionRow, secondActionRow);

      
      
   
  
  const spielersucheerweitertEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle(`Spieler suchen Spieler `)
  .setColor('#00ff0c')
  .setDescription(stripIndents`Drücke auf denn Button um eine Spielersuche Anzufragen!`)
  .setFooter({ text: 'YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY'})
  .setTimestamp();
  
 
  
 
     
  const buttonsa = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('buttonanfrage')
          .setEmoji('')
                    .setLabel('Spielersuche Anfragen')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
            );
      
      
      client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (interaction.isButton()) {
            const buttonID = interaction.customId
            if (buttonID === 'buttonanfrage') {
              await interaction.showModal(modals);
            }
        }
    });

  createanfragechannel.send({ embeds: [spielersucheerweitertEmbed], components: [buttonsa] });
  await interaction.reply({ content: 'Spielersuche Embed wurde versendet!', ephemeral: true });

  client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        if (interaction.customId === "minput") {
            await interaction.reply({ content:'**Wähle deine Plattform!**', components: [pfmenü], ephemeral: true });
            var ginputdata = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('grundinput');
            var sinputdata = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('spielinput');
         
          }
        } else if (interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) {
          const selected = await interaction.values.join(', ');
          
          const spielersucheerweitertEmbedfertig = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setTitle(`${ginputdata}`)
          .setColor('#00ff0c')
          .setFooter({ text: 'YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY'})
          .setTimestamp()
          .addFields(
            {
              name: '**Spiel:**',
              value: `${sinputdata}`,
              inline: true,
            },
            {
              name: `**Plattform:**:`,
              value: `${selected}`,
              inline: false,
            },
          );
         
          if (interaction.customId === "pfmenü") {
            const member = await interaction.member.fetch();
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Spielersuche erfolgreich Angefragt!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
            return await anfragechannel.send({  content: `**Anfrage von:** <@${member.id}>`, embeds: [spielersucheerweitertEmbedfertig] });
          }
                
          
          };
        });
  
  
  
   

}


};
```

tried to define something else but it didn't work

Comment: You either set `ginputdata`/`sinputdata` or use it in an embed. You are not doing both.

Comment: I use it in the "spielersucheerweitertEmbedfertig" embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should focus on where your variables is saved. The variable sinputdata is saved inside the function. The function is like a piece of code that is extracted from the file and ran without really saving variables inside of the function. So every time the function is ran, all your variables are reset.

In other words, you need to save the data you want to keep outside of the function. Therefore, you should make a table at the beginning of your module. Every functions inside the module will be able to edit the table and read the values of it. In addition, everything will be saved (I mean, if you reload the bot, every data will be lost so you need to save everything in a database). Back to the table, the table will include the discordid and the sinputdata value. First, you will set the sinputdata value in the table when you receive it. Then, you will be able to use the sinputdata value when the function is ran a new time.

At the top (under `const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, TextInputStyle, StringSelectMenuBuilder, Events, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder } = require('discord.js');`), write `let sinputvalues = {};`

Then, instead of `var sinputdata = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('spielinput');`, write `sinputvalues[interaction.user.id] = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('spielinput');`.

Finally, replace

```
{
   name: '**Spiel:**',
   value: `${sinputdata}`,
   inline: true,
 },
```

to

```
{
   name: '**Spiel:**',
   value: `${sinputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`,
   inline: true,
 },
```